# whats is the difference in these dimensions

Tags: eaglecad, dimensions

I am wondering what's the difference in these both highlighted dimensions.
[image]

Comment: One gives the lead pitch of the part, and the other is an indicator of the scale of the image.

Comment: 5mm is the pitch size but I didn't get the meaning of grid 17.5mm in the above image. kindly elaborate it a little.

Comment: No, 5mm is the distance between the two tick marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Grid* is distance between pads, *5 mm* is just reference size for the drawing.

If you will apply 5 mm dimension size to the resistor drawing (use ruler on your monitor) you most probably get 3.5 of 5 mm dimensions between resistor's green pads.

Comment: What is grid 17.5mm in the above image ? 5mm is the center-to-center b/w pins/pads

Comment: Grid: look here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grid and here https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-eagle-board-layout/arranging-the-board. if you set EAGLE's "Grid" to 17.5 mm your pads will be put exactly to the grid lines. 5mm is the reference measurement for real size of the package.